# Перед «которые» ставится запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Покажи тогда те фотографии, которые у тебя есть.

Answer (score 1):

Это СПП: *Покажи тогда те фотографии* - главное предложение, *которые у тебя есть* - придаточное определительное предложение. Между главным и придаточным предложениями ставится запятая.

Определительное придаточное предложение определяет какое-то существительное или местоимение из главной части и отвечает на вопросы «какой?», «который?».

Answer (score 0):

Да, сложноподчиненное предложение.